# Next and previous month not working in mozila firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My script below working for google chrome but not working for Mozilla Firefox. I can't find out problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var x = 0;
    $("#next").click(function (e) {
    var divs = $('#SelectedMonth').text();
  x++; //or whatever offset
  var CurrentDate = new Date(divs);
  var SelectedMonth=CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() + 1);
  $("#txtDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm  ', new Date(SelectedMonth)));
  $("#SelectedMonth").text($.datepicker.formatDate('MM yy  ', new Date(SelectedMonth)));
    });
 var y = 0;
    $("#prev").click(function (e) {
    var divs = $('#SelectedMonth').text();
  y++; //or whatever offset
  var CurrentDate = new Date(divs);
  var SelectedMonth=CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() - 1);
  $("#txtDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm  ', new Date(SelectedMonth)));
  $("#SelectedMonth").text($.datepicker.formatDate('MM yy  ', new Date(SelectedMonth)));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Pre" id="prev"/><span id="SelectedMonth">January 2016</span><input type="button" value="Next"  id="next"/>
```

Comment: You did not use the snipplet right. You do not put html markup in the script. What does the PHP output look like for date?

Comment: Please run this in mozila and chrome, then click on next and pre button. You can see the problem.

Comment: Now that the sample works after my update and you putting what php outputs I was able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a data attribute to hold a date string that Firefox understands on how to parse.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = 0;
  $("#next, #prev").click(function(e) {

    var divs = $('#SelectedMonth').data("date"),
        dir = this.id === "next" ? 1 : -1,
        CurrentDate = new Date(divs);
    CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() + dir);
    x += dir;
    $("#txtDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm  ', CurrentDate));
    $("#SelectedMonth")
      .text($.datepicker.formatDate('MM yy  ', CurrentDate))
      .data("date", CurrentDate);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Pre" id="prev" /><span id="SelectedMonth" data-date="01/01/2013">January 2016</span>
<input type="button" value="Next" id="next" />
```